# Referencia y copia en C#

Tags: c#

Tengo estos tres métodos y he realizado estas 3 pruebas:

```
    [Fact]
    public void TestRefsLibro3()
    {
        //arrange
        var libro = new Libro("Hola");

        //act

        cambiaNombreRef(ref libro, "Cambiado");

        // assert

        Assert.Equal("Cambiado", libro.Nombre);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void TestRefsLibro4()
    {
        //arrange
        var libro = new Libro("Hola");

        //act

        cambiaNombreNoRef(libro, "Cambiado");

        // assert

        Assert.Equal("Cambiado", libro.Nombre);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void TestRefsLibro5()
    {
        //arrange
        var libro = new Libro("Hola");

        //act

        cambiaNombre(libro, "Cambiado");

        // assert

        Assert.Equal("Cambiado", libro.Nombre);
    }

    public void cambiaNombreRef(ref Libro l, String n)
    {
        l = new Libro(n);
        l.Nombre = n;
    }

    public void cambiaNombreNoRef( Libro l, String n)
    {
        l = new Libro(n);
        l.Nombre = n;
    }

    public void cambiaNombre(Libro l, String n)
    {
        l.Nombre = n;
    }
```

De las 3 pruebas, no pasa la segunda y no termino de entender el motivo. Si se supone que cuando pases el argumento a un método, este pasa por copia, tiene sentido que en la primera cambie, pues al crear el nuevo objeto, estas trabajando con la referencia, por lo que la referencia del objeto pasa a apuntar al nuevo, el cual cambias. En el segundo caso es lo opuesto, cambias la referencia del objeto que te pasan por copia, por lo que no afecta el cambio al objeto original.

Sin embargo, no entiendo en el tercer caso por qué sí pasa, si estoy pasando el objeto por copia, al acceder a los atributos del mismo y variarlos, no deberían no cambiarse en el original? Sin embargo, sí pasa los test, por lo que si ha cambiado.

Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por defecto, en C# el paso de parámetros es por valor y supongo que es lo que te está liando. Aunque esto es así, en el caso de las clases lo que se pasa por valor es **la referencia** a la variable, no se pasa una copia del objeto.

Por eso, mientras no modifiques esta referencia (como haces en los otros casos con `new Libro`), la referencia sigue apuntando al objeto original, y cambiar las propiedades del objeto dentro del método las cambia en el objeto original también.

Analicemos caso por caso. En el primer test al llamar a `cambiaNombreRef`, se le pasa una referencia a la referencia, valga la redundancia, por lo que al cambiar esta (con `new Libro(n)`), la referencia original también cambia apuntando al nuevo objeto que has creado.

En el segundo caso, al llamar a `cambiaNombreNoRef` lo que le llega al método es una copia de la referencia al objeto original. Al ser una copia, cambiar la referencia con `new Libro(n)` no modifica a donde apunta el objeto original, con lo que no modifica el valor de `Nombre`.

Y llegamos al tercer caso, que es el que parece que te sorprende. Como digo al principio, al llamar a `cambiaNombre` al método le llega el valor de la referencia al objeto original. Como en ningún momento cambiamos esta referencia, las modificaciones que se hacen en las propiedades se están haciendo apuntando al objeto original, efectivamente modificándolas en el mismo.

Es un poco difícil explicar esto por escrito y yo no soy el mejor profesor del mundo, pero espero que te haya ayudado un poco a resolver tu duda.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Ahora me ha quedado claro, y lo has explicado genial!